# Bonding Electric Vehicles: Which System to Implement (safety)?

Tags: safety, grounding

I am currently working on building an autonomous electrical vehicle and would like some input on which bonding system would be safest and most practical. The system battery is 48V (dc) and which feeds motors as well as runs through a series of isolated converters for lower voltage systems (24V, 12V). My understanding of the options as well as pros and cons are as follows:

**Traditional Chassis Bonding**
Pros: Simple, all enclosures/chassis at equipotential

Cons: If someone is touching the chassis and a positive node, you are the connection between hot and cold (with your heart in between).

**Isolated DC System** 
Pro : First ground fault (i.e.; to chassis) will do nothing

Cons: 1) safe to touch until after first fault (imagine someone is standing on earth and touches chassis if first fault is to chassis) 2) fault protection will not trip til second fault.  3) Common mode currents across different enclosures could affect electronics after first ground fault
4) Detecting first ground fault (when it occurs and where)

**Impedance Bonding**
Pro: 1) If impedance selected properly perhaps the impedance of the resistor could reduce risk to personnel. 2) chassis and enclosures at same potential. 3) if impedance is selected properly circuit protection could still trip in ground fault condition.3) Monitoring the voltage over the impedance will allow me to detect if there is a ground fault that doesn't trip circuit breakers allowing me to electronically trip upstream (main) circuit breaker in this condition (via PLC).

Cons: 1) If impedance is not properly calculated either circuit protection may not trip properly (arc flash needs quick trip), or if too low personnel is no longer safe.

I am leaning towards impedance bonding. The low voltage systems are isolated so I don't think I could use them as bond return path (I don't know how isolated dc-dc converters would respond to an influx in ground current). Online people are generally recommending isolated system, however as this system's battery is at 48V DC (not HVDC battery) I think that the risk of an isolated system is low enough that this system would be the best option.

Please correct any misunderstandings, and any input/experiences would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't [impedance bonding](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB828GB828&biw=1493&bih=895&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=9ZscXr-dBZWbjLsPzO6D0Ac&q=impedance+bonding&oq=impedance+bonding&gs_l=img.3...14927.14927..15340...0.0..0.40.79.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.NFznodUirmk&ved=0ahUKEwj_6-HVgIHnAhWVDWMBHUz3AHoQ4dUDCAc&uact=5) something used on the tracks of railways? Are you designing a locomotive?

Comment: not necessarily a train thing @Andyaka

Comment: Then please leave a link that I can read.

Comment: That hilarious, most online examples are for railways (also DC systems). I went to school for power distribution, and when we learned it was mostly in a factory context. My main reason for this system is to limit potential potential risks (I see) in isolated and chassis bonding system (reasons stated above). Any flaws in my logic would be appreciated. As this is an autonomous vehicle with only digital oversight no electricians will be on hand to monitor so the decision to be made has to be safe all the time.

Comment: Check out IER vehicles (insulated earth return), used for vehicles delivering flammable liquids...

Comment: If IER is what I think it is its not exactly what I am talking about. The difference between bonding and return (ground) is that bonding is a return path for a short circuit in the case of a wire shorting to metal frame.  Insulated returns does not give a return path for current to battery in case of fault.

Comment: I would recommend starting with standards documents that may cover this.  [Here is good start place](https://www.sae.org/binaries/content/assets/cm/content/standards/p90475.pdf).

Comment: thank you @relayman357

Comment: @FuzMunkey IER basically means that there is a wiring loom to supply **all** components and another to provide the return path to the battery - the chassis or frame is never part of the circuit. Safety: to minimise the risks of a spark. Also used for vehicles in mines from what a miner told me.

Comment: In my context all electrical components are mounted to steel backplane, backplane is connected to enclosure, enclosure is connected to chassis. Imagine there is a ground fault within the enclosure, the chassis is now energized. Where does this current go? Im not so much worried about a spark. If there is no bonding system after the first ground fault the energy has no return route hence no short circuit current draw (which trips protection equipment). If someone touches chassis while standing on earth the potential between them and the ground could be 48V or higher (with them being the short)

Comment: If you are worried about touching energized nodes, I'm not sure how else you can get there except to use a conventional DC GFCI on an isolated system (or a system where the chassis is grounded at a single point).  As you pointed out, a passive impedance bond would be touchy to set up and dependent on the rise time and amplitude of the fault current, instead of having a driven saturable current sense transformer for fault current detection as in a DC GFCI.

Comment: _"I am currently working on building an **autonomous** electrical vehicle"_ - this vehicle will not have a driver or passengers? When will people be contacting it?

Comment: You are asking questions that are very easy to answer, for anyone capable of building an autonomous electric vehicle.

Comment: its an agbot. after testing last summer we determined that in small faming communities people come check out robots, at one point some kids pressed the big red e-stop for fun. After a day of reading standards. at this point the question is really to ground to chassis only (single point grounding), or to connect chassis to anode. If not connected to chassis, depending on isolation, wont positive charge build up over time on chassis (open field could be lightning risk), however if connected it could be a person risk. HV vehicles are defined as 60V DC and we are 54V DC when charged which is close